# thread exiting with uncaught exception in android socket programing

Tags: android

This is my Server side code snippet. and being new to android programing i was unable to fix the errors messages showed by LogCat. My application crashes unexpectedly and i am using emulator. please help me or suggest me how can i fix these errors. Thanks!

```
    package server.activity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView serverStatus;

    // default ip
    public static String SERVERIP = "";

    // designate a port
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 1234;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.server);
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

        SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        fst.start();
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                if (SERVERIP != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                        }
                    });
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                    while (true) {
                        // listen for incoming clients
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // do whatever you want to the front end
                                        // this is where you can be creative
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                                }
                            });
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Error");
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // gets the ip address of your phone's network
    private String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
             // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
             serverSocket.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

}
```

This is the output from the LogCat

```
11-29 19:33:36.051: D/AndroidRuntime(571): Shutting down VM
11-29 19:33:36.059: W/dalvikvm(571): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-29 19:33:36.070: E/AndroidRuntime(571): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{server.activity/server.activity.ServerActivityActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server.activity.ServerActivityActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c07820
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server.activity.ServerActivityActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c07820
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571):  ... 11 more
11-29 19:33:36.230: I/dalvikvm(571): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-29 19:33:36.857: I/dalvikvm(571): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-29 19:33:46.360: I/Process(571): Sending signal. PID: 571 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says it can't find the class for `server.activity.ServerActivityActivity` and your activity is actually `server.activity.ServerActivity`. This is most likely an error in your android-manifest.xml. Check that file and ensure you didn't accidentally supply the wrong activity name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the intent that launches your `ServerActivity`.

Your activity name is `ServerActivity` but you try to start a activity named `ServerActivityActivity` according to this line:

> 11-29 19:33:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(571): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   server.activity.ServerActivityActivity in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c07820

So most likely just a "typo" if you will.

Comment: Thanks alextsc @Last Warrior .Your answer helped me fixing error, though it was a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Code is like that

```
<activity android:name=".ServerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
```

above the

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also check this line is that present

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="server.activity"
```